# Mathematica Nested Manipulates Lag

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Ok! I'm working towards building a nested manipulate command that will solve n number of damped oscillating masses in series (with fixed endpoints). I have everything pretty much working but I have one problem - when I increase the number of oscillators, my initial conditions lag behind a bit. For example, if I set n to 4, Mathematica says I still only have 2 initial conditions (the starting number - position and velocity for one oscillator). When I then move to 3, I now have 8 (from my 4 oscillators) - which is too many for the state space equations, and it all fails. What is going on?

(Yes, I know that my initial conditions aren't going to be put in correctly yet, I'm just trying to get them to match up first).

```
coupledSMD[n_, m_, k_, b_, f_, x0_, v0_, tmax_] :=
    Module[{aM, bM, cM, dM},
    aM = Join[Table[Boole[i == j - n], {i, n}, {j, 2 n}], 
      Join[
        If[n != 1,DiagonalMatrix[-2 k/m Table[1, {n}]] + 
          k/m DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {n - 1}], 1] + 
          k/m DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {n - 1}], -1],
          {{-2 k/m}}], 
        If[n != 1,DiagonalMatrix[-2 b/m Table[1, {n}]] + 
          b/m DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {n - 1}], 1] + 
          b/m DiagonalMatrix[Table[1, {n - 1}], -1],
          {{-2 b/m}}], 2]];
    bM = Join[Table[0, {n}, {1}], Table[1/m, {n}, {1}]];
    cM = Table[Boole[i == j], {i, n}, {j, 2 n}];
    dM = Table[0, {n}, {1}];
    OutputResponse[ 
       {StateSpaceModel[{aM, bM, cM, dM}], Flatten[Join[x0, v0]]},
       f, {t, 0, tmax}]
]
Manipulate[
  With[{
    x0s = Table[Subscript[x, i, 0], {i, 1, n}],
    v0s = Table[Subscript[v, i, 0], {i, 1, n}],
    initialx = Sequence @@ Table[{{Subscript[x, i, 0], 0}, -10, 10}, {i, 1, n}],
    initialv = Sequence @@ Table[{{Subscript[v, i, 0], 0}, -10, 10}, {i, 1, n}]},
    Manipulate[
      myplot = coupledSMD[n, m, k, b, f, x0s, v0s, tmax];
      Plot[myplot, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> yheight {-1, 1}, 
        PlotLegends -> Table[Subscript[x, i, 0], {i, 1, n}]],
      Style["Initial Positions", Bold],
      initialx,
      Delimiter,
      Style["Initial Velocities", Bold],
      initialv,
      Delimiter,
      Style["System conditions", Bold],
      {{m, 1, "Mass(kg)"}, 0.1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
      {{k, 1, "Spring Constant(N/m)"}, 0.1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
      {{b, 0, "Damping Coefficient(N.s/m)"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
      {{f, 0, "Applied Force"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
      Delimiter,
      Style["Plot Ranges", Bold],
      {tmax, 10, 100},
      {{yheight, 10}, 1, 100},
      Delimiter,
      ControlPlacement -> Flatten[{Table[Right, {2 n + 2}], Table[Left, {8}]}]
    ]],
  {n, 1, 4, 1}
]
```

**Edit:** Updated the code. It works now, but I'm still getting the errors. I'm guessing that it has something to do with a time lag in the updating process? - That some parts are getting updated before others. Again, it seems to be working perfectly, except it throws these errors (the errors seem superfluous to me, as if they are remnants in the code, but not actually causing a problem)

But I don't really know what I'm talking about :)